# Ejecutar consulta mysql cuando este seguro de que no hay otro registro con el mismo codigo

Tags: php, mysql

estoy teniendo un pequeño inconveniente. Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
function RandomStringN($length){
    $characters = '123456789';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++) { $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; } return $randomString;
}
```

Lo que hace este script es que por medio de RandomStringN(4) me devuelve un numero aleatorio de 4 digitos.

Tengo una tabla en mysql que lleva un registro ID, Codigo, Nombre. Quiero realizar un Insert en esa tabla con datos por ejemplo. ID => 1, COD => 1425, Nombre => Tal nombre. Pero antes de realizar el INSERT quiero comprobar que el codigo aleatorio que se esta generando por medio del RandomStringN(4) no se encuentra asignado a ningun registro de la tabla.

Lo he intentado con:

```
$cod = RandomStringN(4);  
$cons = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE cod = '$cod'"));
if($cons>=1) $cod = RandomString(4);
$inst = mysql_query("INSERTAR REGISTRO");
```

Eventualmente ingresa codigos duplicados y es lo que quiero evitar.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y atencion.

Comment: Que versión de PHP estas utilizando, las funciones mysql_* se han borrado en PHP7 hay que utilizar mysqli_*.

Comment: Que tal Carlos, perdon por cuestionarte pero si no querías registros duplicados tenias que haber declarado el campo como UNIQUE para que no admita repeticiones. Por que no alteras la tabla para agregar esto??

Comment: Como dice @VíctorHugoTirado, aunque controles del lado de PHP, no deberías delegar la unicidad de los registros a la lógica del programa, sino controlarla a nivel de base de datos mediante una restricción `UNIQUE`. Eso, aparte de asegurar 100% que en ningún caso ese valor estará repetido, optimiza la tabla, porque es al mismo tiempo un índice para filtrar datos por esa columna. Aunque si me permites preguntaría qué sentido tiene un tu modelo de datos generar una columna aleatoria y por qué tiene que ser única cuando tienes un `ID` ¿? Otra cosa es que si tienes PHP 7, no funcionará `mysql_`